# Why does this particular algorithm work?

Tags: algorithms, binary-operations

I was reading about gray codes. There I found this algorithm.

```
int g (int n) 
{
    return n ^ (n >> 1);
}
```

Given a number $n$, this finds the $n$th gray code.

Suppose if $n=10$, the answer would be $1111$. Since $n=10(1010)$, 
$$\begin{align} 
n>>1 &= 0101 \\ 
n \wedge (n>>1) &= 1111. 
\end{align}$$

I can understand the working. But I don't really understand how they derived this? I mean can somebody give me the intuition behind this?

Comment: do you know what is grey code?

Comment: Yeah sir.If you start with 0,you have to construct sequence in such a way that previous and current term should differ only by a bit.

Comment: i tried to  show some examples,i hope it would help you about how it is derived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int g(int n)
    { 
     return  n^(n>>1);
    }

    int main()
    {
    int n=10;
    cout<<g(n)<<endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

yes you are right
answer is $15=1111$

the main point is that  ^ mark is xor,which means that Exclusive disjunction or exclusive oris a logical operation that outputs true whenever both inputs differ (one is true, the other is false)

there is time table for it

```
XOR Truth Table
  Input     Output
A   B
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   0
```

now >> symbol means simple divide by $2$,in  your case $10/2=5$ or  $0101$

now we have

$1010$ xor $(0101)$=$1111$

for generally let us find grey codes from 0 to n

```
#include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int g(int n)
    { 
     return  n^(n>>1);
    }

    int main()
    {
    for (int n=0;n<=10;n++){
    cout<<g(n)<<endl;

}
    return 0;
    }
```

answer
http://codepad.org/xAMnNA0r

Actually  ^ mark shows true at this places where  this  two sequence differ from each other,which  of course is basic idea behind of grey code
additional information you can check there

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GrayCode.html

look also there please

http://www.most.gov.mm/techuni/media/BinaryToGrayCodeConverter.pdf

Comment: Sorry,i really don't understand the intuition behind the function from this answer.I can understand how that works.I just want to know why that works.? Why right shift by 1 is done ? Why it is XORed with n ,why not with any ? Etc are the questions from my side ?

Comment: why it is  right shift by $1$?let us take  example of $1$,which which has code $01$,now how to generate code which differ only by one integer?sure we can shift left,but this wont give answer,so in our case,this number would be $2$,or $10$,then 3  or $101$, and so on,it is just intuitive ,we  know what does xor do right?by right shifting we  just removing last digit ,so just tests on numbers

Comment: Oh cool i understood sir ! :) Thanks a lot...Please add that in you r answer if possible.

Comment: please  check last link also

Comment: This answer does not help how the code is working. Can someone plz explain?

Answer (score 4):

`n^(n>>1)` xors each bit of `n` with the bit immediately to its left. The result is a collection of bits that encode the positions where the bits of `n` *change* from 0 to 1 or vice versa as we read them aloud from left to right.

In order to see that this produces a Gray code, we need to prove two things:

**The transformation is injective**, that is, we can reconstruct `n` if we know `n^(n>>1)`. This is actually only true if we know that the first bit of `n` is 0, or if our `>>` operator always shifts in a zero bit at the left end even if `n` is negative.

Once we know that the leftmost bits of `n` is 0, it is easy to find out what `n` is given `n^(n>>1)` -- just start by writing down a `0`, and find the rest of the bits from left to right -- each bit is *the same* as the previous one if the corresponding bit of `n^(n>>1)` is zero, and *the opposite* if the corresponding bit of `n^(n>>1)` is one.

**Whenever we add 1 to `n`, exactly one bit of `n^(n>>1)` changes.** Imagine adding one to `n` by pencil-and-paper addition in binary. The binary representation of `n` will end by a zero followed by $k$ ones (for some $k$ that might be zero). So the addition goes

```
 ab..cd011..11
+00..00000..01
--------------
 ab..cd100..00
```

where the carries stop at the point where a `0` becomes a `1`.

Now we can see that the last $k$ bits of the original `n^(n>>1)` were `10..00`, and these are still the last $k$ bits of `(n+1)^((n+1)>>1`. On the other hand, the $(k+1)$th bit (corresponding to the bit position that changed from `0` to `1`) was `d` before, but is now the opposite of `d`. And clearly no bits to the *left* of this position can have changed.

So, as expected, exactly one bit changes between `n^(n>>1)` and `(n+1)^((n+1)>>1`.

Comment: Perfect ! :D Thanks :D